# how to decode a string(not bytes[]) in utf-8 format into another string in java?

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, utf-8

for some reason, I have to decode string in chinese character. like this 
“\u961c”，this string is utf-8 of “阜”

I know how to decode bytes[] into Unicode characters.but is there an easy way decode String into Unicode characters?

By the way,When I get “阜”.getBytes. I get -100,-104,-23.
Is that means

1001110 10010100 11101001 in binary?

But I think \u961c　Unicode should be 1001 0110 0001 1100 in binary or something

and it's utf-8 format should be 11101001 10011000 10011100 in binary

Comment: 阜 (U+961C) is `\u961C` in UTF-16 but `E9 98 9C` in UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, there is no such method to encode a `String` object (not entirely accurate, there is an encoding, but that's UTF-16).

The only way is to encode to a `byte[]`. So if you need UTF-8 data, then you need a `byte[]`. If you have a `String` that contains unexpected data, then the problem is at some earlier place that incorrectly converted some binary data to a `String` (i.e. it was using the wrong encoding).

This one will work, but for `bytes[]`

```
Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(myString)
```

Comment: `Charset.encode()` returns a `ByteBuffer`. To get a `byte[]` from that, you would have call `Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(myString).array()`. Otherwise, use `myString.getBytes("UTF-8")` or `myString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` instead.